# laravel access to model constant in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access a class constant in a Blade file without using the full path:

```php
class PaymentMethod extends Model
{
    const PAYPAL_ACCOUNT = 'paypal_account';
    const CREDIT_CARD    = 'credit_card';
}
```

In my blade file this works:

```
{{ App\Classes\Models\PaymentMethod::CREDIT_CARD }}
```

...but this throws `Class 'PaymentMethod' not found`

```
{{ PaymentMethod::CREDIT_CARD }}
```

Is there a less verbose way to access this constant?

Answer (score 24):

You may use aliases:

in your `config\app.php` under `aliases` section :

```
aliases => [
     ....
    'PaymentMethod' => App\Classes\Models\PaymentMethod::class
]
```

then use it in your blade file

```
{{ PaymentMethod::CREDIT_CARD }}
```

Comment: ok this work. but need add every class with constants. it is less acceptable

Answer (score 8):

Found this thread while trying to solve the same problem. Decided to go with [injecting the class](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#service-injection):

```
namespace App\Services\Auth\IAM;

class IAMConstants
{
    const GUARD_WEB = 'web';
    const GUARD_ADMIN = 'admin';
}
```

Then in Blade:

```
@inject('constants', 'App\Services\Auth\IAM\IAMConstants')
...
<option value="{{ $constants::GUARD_WEB }}">App user</option>
```

The injected class should be small since it will carry in all its dependencies.

Comment: Doesn't the injected class need to be a registered service provider?